# Derivation of Trace

Tags: matrices

I am curious about a formula in http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%B7%A1

$$\frac{\partial\text{tr}(A^{-1})}{\partial A}=-(A^{-2})^T$$

I have tried to prove this. We have $A^{-1}=\frac{A^*}{|A|}$, and we must prove

$$\frac{\partial\frac{1}{|A|}\text{tr}(A^*)}{\partial A}=-((\frac{A^*}{|A|})^2)^T$$

But this is not a very easy to prove the equality. Is there any wise method to prove? Any advice is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:A\rightarrow A^{-1}$. The derivative is $Df_A:H\rightarrow trace(-A^{-1}HA^{-1})=trace(-A^{-2}H)=(-(A^{-2})^T,H)$ where $(U,V)=trace(U^TV)$ is the standard dot product over the real square matrices. Finally the gradient is $\nabla_f(A)=-(A^{-2})^T$ (by definition  $(\nabla_f(A),H)=Df_A(H)$ for every square matrix $H$).